# StageVideo on mobile devices

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, ios, air

I wanted to display H.264 videos with air packaging for mobile  and run into a problem.
is StageVideo avaiable on mobile devices running  IOS or android?
I use air 2.6 sdk for packaging and it seems there is no StageVideo on ipad?
I can use StageWebView but because of limitation of it ( it always
rendered on the top) this is not an option for me.
Is any schedule when would StageVideo be available for mobile? maybe
air 2.7 sdk?
What are other option to display such video  format?
Thank you

Comment: I'm having the same experience.  stage.stageVideos.length is always 0 on the iPad and the StageVideoAvailabilityEvent never fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Flash Player 10.2 for Android Release Notes](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/895/cpsid_89556.html):

> **Hardware accelerated video rendering for H.264 (On upcoming Honeycomb OS release only)**
>
> Flash Player 10.2 leverages the Stage
>   Video rendering pipeline to enable
>   users of Android 3.0 tablets, like the
>   Motorola Xoom, to enjoy smooth
>   playback of high-definition  video in
>   Flash Player.   Users will experience
>   reduced CPU usage and higher frame
>   rates for existing H.264 video
>   content.

So that is on Android Honeycomb only.

Answer (score 1):

StageVideo is possible on iPhone with the latest AIR SDK.

You need to download the latest SDK and do an overlay install http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/908/cpsid_90810.html

Now build your file with StageVideo. Follow the standard packing steps for mobile.

But set rendermode to GPU instead of CPU. If you set rendermode wrong usually you can hear the audio.

This is how i got it working on my end on iPhone. However on Android I am getting no video but the audio stream even though Air 3.1 is installed on the phone. Am still looking into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, StageVideo doesn't seem to work for me in an Android 3.0 Honeycomb tablet (Acer Iconia) with Flash Player 10.2

When I use StageVideo only sound can be heard but video doesn't show, and I think I'm doing it properly, because in the desktop Flash Player for Firefox it works.

In the Iconia I have to resort to using regular video, not StageVideo.

Comment: This has been my experience as well on Android. Which is curious under any other circumstances StageVideo simply fails and doesn't play anything audio or otherwise. This is further strange since the Air client on android is AIR 3.1 which has support for StageVideo (on iOS this works). Makes me feel it's a bug or there is some setting we are missing.

Comment: I think it's only supported in AIR iOS thus far (not even in AIR desktop!)